# Wrong width of `inline-block` parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working with some HTML/CSS which lines up `<li>` elements horizontally using a lot of `display:inline-block` rules. I've traced a JS bug to a `$("ol").width()` which measures the width of the element incorrectly - seemingly because of the width of the `<li>` contents?

Here's an example of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/q01ng8b6/ - note how the red border of the `<ol>` element doesn't go all the way around the contents:

[image]

Here's an example of how removing a width on the `<li>` contents fixes the size of my `<ol>` element: http://jsfiddle.net/q01ng8b6/1/ - note how the red border of the properly goes all the way around the contents.

I don't understand what's happening here - how could a rule changing the width of the "grandchildren" have such a pronounced effect on the width of my `<ol>` element? Is this a browser bug or standards compliant?

Comment: Applying width 100% to an element with a parent of width auto doesn't really make sense. What are you trying to achieve by setting the width of the img? I see you have a min-width on your li elements. Maybe you should set the min-width of your imgs to 100%?

Comment: @Tatermelon - Unfortunately the `<img>` elements are only sample content - part of the work I'm doing now involves potentially putting any arbitrary content in those list items. So it's difficult to rely on applying CSS rules to the contents of the `<li>` elements. Equally, that's why this behavior concerns me: someone changing the width of an image in this list could upset the JS which measures its size.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a browser bug, but possibly an inadequately tightly defined spec.

What appears to be happening is that the calculation of the width of the li elements has multiple solutions. Its width depends on its contents (shrink-to-fit), and its contents width depends on their container (100%). Any value from 0 to infinity will work.

Now, for the ol element, the shrink-to-fit algorithm applies. From [CSS basic box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#shrink-to-fit)

> Calculation of the shrink-to-fit width is similar to calculating the width of a table cell using the automatic table layout algorithm. Roughly: calculate the preferred width by formatting the content without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur, and also calculate the preferred minimum width, e.g., by trying all possible line breaks. CSS does not define the exact algorithm. Thirdly, find the available width: in this case, this is the width of the containing block minus the used values of ‘margin-left’, ‘border-left-width’, ‘padding-left’, ‘padding-right’, ‘border-right-width’, ‘margin-right’, and the widths of any relevant scroll bars.
>
> Then the shrink-to-fit width is: min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width).
>
> Define in more detail, using a text by David Baron.

The spec is clearly inadequate for this case, but it seems that for the purposes of the preferred minimum width, the li width solution = 0 is used, while for the preferred width, the li width solution = intrinsic width of the img is used. These choices don't seem unreasonable to me, but I don't know of any part of the spec that requires them.

Assuming those values for your example, the width of the ol element is the available width, which is what you see.

Of course, the li and img widths cannot be rendered in multiple solutions, and there is nothing to constrain the width of the li elements to be proportionate to their container, so they render according to the img elements intrinsic widths, overflowing their ol container.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to tweak the position of the parent and children element to force the container to grow with them. e.g.

```
.my-horizontal-ul {
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:absolute;
}
.my-horizontal-ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.my-horizontal-ul li img {
}
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j26y2p09/)

Comment: Unfortunately, several of the rules you dropped are important - such as the min-width.

Comment: Can you not just put it back? I removed it just to show the bones of the positioning.

Comment: When I add the properties back dealing with the widths of `<li>` and `<img>` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/j26y2p09/1/

Comment: Have you looked into flex box for this solution? http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html#row. I would try to give you an example but my work computer is using an old ie. which doesn't support flexbox.

Comment: I'd love to but this component need to target too many old browsers. Really what I'm looking for here is an explanation and from there I'll be able to make a decision on how/whether this needs to be aggressively refactored.